# Laptop shortly freezing while on battery

Tags: laptop, freeze, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro X 2021, and it works well. The only problem is that while working on the battery it sometimes freezes (e.g. when I'm typing a text there might be delays in text appearing on the screen). I tried advice from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/608787/my-laptop-freezes-when-on-battery?newreg=9b0e61f6fa6c453b9e5cc0687232518b), but it didn't solve the problem. Sometimes disabling Microsoft AC Adapter and Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery helps for till the next reboot, so I think that's a software problem.
I tried to reinstall Windows, I think the first month this problem wasn't appearing, but then it started again. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you reinstalled Windows to no avail, try updating all drivers including BIOS and Power Driver.

Comment: Check the power management settings. It is possible that the CPU is running on a slower frequency on battery than it is when connected to a charger. Checking the resource monitor for high CPU usage while such freezes occur would help identifying the issue.

Comment: All drivers are updated and up to date. There's only one BIOS version, I have the same (0606). I take the drivers from the official page: https://www.mi.com/service/notebook/drivers/A30

 Also, I changed all settings in power management, now On Battery has exactly the same settings as Plugged In, but still, that doesn't solve the problem. That's really strange issue